# Rspec & FactoryGirl 'Cannot call create unless parent is saved'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm sure that my issue is pretty easy to resolve. However, I cannot find how or where to resolve it. Currently I am trying to test the `#follow` method on my User model. Here is the test that I have:

```
describe "#follow & #following?" do
 before(:each) do
   @other_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
 end

 it "returns false for user following other_user" do
   expect(@user.following?(@other_user)).to eq(false)
 end

 it "returns true for user following other_user" do
   @user.follow(@other_user)
   expect(@user.following?(@other_user)).to eq(true)
 end
end
```

Here is the `#follow` method:

```
def follow(other_user)
 active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
end
```

The error that is being returned is `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`. Obviously the parent in question here is `@other_user`. Now the first test passes as intended because we obviously aren't running a method that calls create like when we run the `#follow` method. My question is how would I save this `@other_user` so that I can create an `active_relationship`.

Here is how `@user` is being presented:

```
before { @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) }
subject { @user }
```

Also, `@user` is working with all other tests. When running `.persisted?` on both `@user` & `@other_user` I receive `true`.

Comment: In the spec file, where and how is `@user` being created?

Comment: Is it really the `@other_user` that is not saved? My guess would be that `@user` is not saved. Call `persisted?` on both of them to test this out. Furthermore you might want to call `errors` on both of them, perhaps the factory does not return valid instances.

Comment: `FactoryGirl.build(:user)` returns an unsave user, i doubt that `@user.persisted?` returns `true`... Please add `@user.save` before `@user.follow(@other_user)` and test if that let's your example pass...

Comment: @spickermann So I tested `@other_user.persisted?` and then changed it to `@user`, or so I thought. I ran `@user.persisted?` again, like spickermann has pointed out, build returns false. Actually creating it will get it to persist, thus saving the parent which is `@user`... You were right all along! Thank you for the help. If there is a better way of going about this, I am all ears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `@user` is not saved, because `Factory.build(:user)` returns unsaved records. Just change your specs to save `@user` before you run that particular example.

I would write the specs like this:

```
subject(:user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user) }

describe "#follow & #following?" do
  let(:other) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  it "returns false for user following other_user" do
    expect(user.following?(other)).to be_false
  end

  context "when following" do
    before do
      user.save
      user.follow(other)
    end

    it "returns true for user following other_user" do
      expect(user.following?(other)).to be_true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As @spickermann pointed out. The actual parent in question was `@user` and NOT `@other_user`. Because I was merely `building` the user it was returning an unsaved object. Thus not allowing us to create an `active_relationship` on an object that had yet to be saved. Changing `build` to `create` has resolved the issue.

Thanks to Spickermann and Ben Y for their participation